# DTO validation attribute does not work with swagger MapType

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I have dto with `TimeSpan` property.

```
[TimeSpanValidation]
public TimeSpan Effort { get; set; }
```

I needed to fill post request's body so I could enter this property. I ended up using `MapType`:

```
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
c.MapType<TimeSpan>(() => new OpenApiSchema
{
    Type = "string",
    Example = new OpenApiString("00.00:00:00")
});
)
```

and a validation attribute:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property | AttributeTargets.Field)]
public class TimeSpanValidationAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public TimeSpanValidationAttribute()
    {
        // some code
    }

    public TimeSpanValidationAttribute(string propertyName)
    {
        // some code
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
        => TimeSpan.TryParse(value?.ToString(), CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("ru-RU"), out _) ?
            ValidationResult.Success : 
            new ValidationResult(ErrorMessage);
}
```

But validation does not work. I assume it parses from json to TimeSpan first then uses validation if only parsing was successful. When it fails I get:
`The JSON value could not be converted to System.TimeSpan. Path: $.effort | LineNumber: 4 | BytePositionInLine: 26.`

I tried to remove MapType, so in swagger my dto was looking like this:

`"effort": { "ticks": 0 }` which is not obvious

and passing `"effort": { "hours": 10 }` does not work either

Is there any way to validate string value from `MapType` before json parsed to TimeSpan?

Answer (score -1):

You shouldn't use TimeSpan type. The model that coming to the your api is json string. Try this way.

```
[TimeSpanValidation]
public string Effort { get; set; }
```